# What are the Ghost of Christmas Present's Brothers?

Tags: plot-explanation, a-christmas-carol-2009

In [A Christmas Carol](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1067106/) staring Jim Carrey, the Ghost of Christmas Present [mentions](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=christmas-carol-a-2009) that he has a lot of brothers.

> **Ghost of Christmas Present:** *[You] Have never walked forth with my elder brothers?*
>
> **Scrooge:** *I don't think that I have. You have many brothers?*
>
> **Ghost of Christmas Present:** *More than 1,800.*

What did he mean by this, who are his brothers?

Comment: That makes no sense though, the first Christmas was in the 4th Century.

Comment: I think everyone is his brother or every preist is his brother.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think that this goes back to the [original Dickens story](http://www.stormfax.com/3dickens.htm) when the Ghost says that he has more than 1800 brothers - i.e. each Ghost of Christmas *Present* comes to Earth for a single day.

> *"Have never walked forth with **the younger members of my family;
>   meaning (for I am very young) my elder brothers born in these later
>   years?"** pursued the Phantom.*
>
> *"I don't think I have," said Scrooge. "I am afraid I have not. Have
>   you had many brothers, Spirit?"*
>
> *"More than eighteen hundred," said the Ghost.*
>
> *"A tremendous family to provide for," muttered Scrooge.*
>
> *The Ghost of Christmas Present rose.*

I think the idea is that a new Ghost is 'created' every Christmas, so at that in 1843 he has 1842 brothers.

Comment: He doesn't say that he has 1842 brothers in the original text. Your other assertions are correct, though.

Answer (score 2):

He suggests that he has 1842 brothers, an Dickens shows that because he wrote and published the book in that year. The ghost of christmas Present every year helps a isolated soul so that they can have a better future.